# Filter users using position in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an app in react-native where I have a list of users and I want to filter them, when I click on a button in the header, using their actual position. How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
export default data = [
   {
      id:1,
      name:"Anastasia",
      photo_path: "https://www.one-voyance.fr/media/cache/slider/images/voyants/anastasia/anastasia.jpg",
      age: "23",
      pratique: "Trans.",
      distance: "200m",
      connected: 1,
      description:"Anastasia, medium pure sans support.Mon don héréditaire me vient de mes grands parents. Prête à vous servir, je m’appuie de mes guides pour vous guider dans votre chemin de vie.Je suis compétente dans tous les domaines. La vie est faite de détours, en connaitre les recoins permet d’avancer sereinement sans se poser de questions. Je vous attends pour une voyance claire et de qualité.",
      //numero:"06 01 02 03 04"
   }
```

Comment: Can you show the sample list of users to be filtered and your code?

Comment: For now I'm just retrieving the data from array, but I'm planning on getting it from a json. Just edited

Comment: What do you mean by position? You mean position in the array?

Comment: No I mean the geolocation of the user

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method provided by an Array to filter the data. A solution would be something like this:

`let tempResults = data.filter(element => element.position === 'Some position')`

For the Button, you'll have to add an onPress event handler, something like below:

`<Button onPress={this.handleButtonPress} />`

And define the handler function as something like:

```
handleButtonPress = () => {
 let tempResults = this.state.data.filter(element => element.position === 'Some position')
 this.setState({dataToBeRendered: tempResults})
}
```

Hope this will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for getting the [Geolocation with React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation). Then you can do whatever you want from your data based on the user's geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

You should `setParams` and pass the `function` and `filter value` to the `header` and perform the operation with `function` received in `params` as shown below

```
this.state = {
 position: "",
 result: []
} 

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {};
return {
headerTitle: {params.position}
headerLeft: <View/>
headerRight: <View><Button onPress={params.handleFilter("200")}>Filter</Button> </View>
}}


componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams(
      Object.assign({}, this.props.navigation.state.params, {
        handleFilter: this.handleFilter,
        position: this.state.position
      })
    );
  }

handleFilter = position => {
  this.setState({ position: position })
  result.filter(data => Number(data.position) < Number(position)) 

}
```